# PHP dropdown only selecting the last item in list

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

I created a drop down list in PHP and it's selecting the last item of the list and I can't figure out why it's doing this.

When I echo the event_id (the value that is returned), it's the last item every time. The list is populated correctly.

```
$forms = mysql_query("select events.event_title, events.event_id, saved_forms.id from events
                     INNER JOIN saved_forms on saved_forms.id = events.event_id
                    where saved_forms.form_type = 'e' and events.event_by = '$my_username'");   

while($form = mysql_fetch_array($forms)){
    $form_id = $form['event_id'];
    $selection.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$form_id\">".$form['event_title']."</OPTION>";
}

?>
<div id="saved_forms">
<tr><td><select name ="saved_form" value ="<? echo $form_id; ?>" onchange="showUser(<? echo $form_id; ?>)">
<Option value="$form_id"><? echo $selection; ?></Select></td><td>Select Existing Form</td></tr>
</div>
```

Comment: What does the generated HTML look like? You should also remove the space between your attributes and values in `<select>`, and not use the `mysql_*` extensions as they have been deprecated - go with `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: It's done through an ajax request, so I'm not sure how to check the html. However, when I echo the event_id (the output), it's the last item of the list.

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you are doing, but to select a value you put "selected" on the option, not a value on the select box, and you should be passing something like `JSON` if it's and `AJAX` request, not `HTML`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here

```
<select name="saved_form" value="<? echo $form_id; ?>" onchange="showUser(<? echo $form_id; ?>)">
```

By giving the `select` tag a value of `$form_id` you have a high chance of overriding the value set in the options. And you shouldn't hardcode the value into the `onchange` event. Try removing the value from `select` and let the `option` tags do the work.

```
<select name="saved_form" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
```

Comment: value isn't even a valid attribute for `<select>`

Comment: I know, but I'm not about to get into random browser quirks

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly but I'm a bit confused. Where is javascript acquiring the value for this.value? Does it just inherit the value from the name of the div (saved_form)?

Comment: "this" refers to the current tag, and "value" is an attribute assigned to the tag, and the `select` tag gets its value from the value of whichever `option` is currently selected.

Comment: Ok, so basically it just relates it to the option tag, right? I don't use javascript much so I really apprecaite the explanation.